# What is the reason to get '64 38' error while downloading cap file?

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I have a sample applet that manages NFC commands. I have no problem compiling and getting the cap file for that application. The problem arises when I try to load this cap file on my card: `Download Cap error: Download cap file failed.` and it returns me status word `64 38` in response to load command `80 E8 00 00 FA...`.

What does that SW code mean? and what is the solution for that?

Comment: Is this jcop3 platform?

Comment: @PaulBastian I am using an FM1280 Fudan card. I don't know whether it is jcop3 platform or not. how can I understand it?

Comment: I remember a similar error due to included debug information in the cap file,  try disable debug symbols

Comment: @PaulBastian how can I disable `including debug information` when compiling?

Comment: Depends on your build setup, there should be an option in the settings, I'm using jcop tools, so it's in eclipse project settings

Comment: @PaulBastian I'm also using Eclipse but I cannot find this option in Javacard setting! Is that in `Java Card > Preferences` or it is in somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0x6400 means "No specific diagnosis (NV-RAM not changed).", i.e. the content was tried to be loaded, but this failed and the card was not modified.
The error you have seems to be a vendor specific error code of this class. When you mention "loading" I take this literally, i.e. this is just the phase when the CAP file is loaded and not yet installed.
When getting errors in the phase this usually means that the CAP file has an issue. The card is checking the byte code if it is supported by the card. Some inspirations what could cause this error:

- Are you using any features not supported by the card? E.g. an **int**?
- Are you using any package which is not available on the card?
- Some older cards were also picky about a combinations of `final`/`static`/`private` modifiers.

Comment: Thank you for the description. Do you mean I have maybe selected the wrong version of a toolkit? Or, I need to install a package that is required by the applet?

Comment: Yes, right, it could also be that the version of the toolkit is not supported. There is a version number included in the export file which must be supported. Installing a package should not work, all the system packages providing ETSI functionality are pre-installed and cannot be replaced.